# Which reaction to use for standard formation enthalpy?

Tags: thermodynamics

> What reaction illustrates $\Delta H^\circ_\mathrm f$ for $\ce{CaCO3}$?

**Answer:** $\ce{Ca(s) + C(s) + 3/2O2(g) -> CaCO3(s)}$.

Ok so why isn't it: $\ce{2Ca(s) + 2C(s) + 3O2(g) -> 2CaCO3}$

Or

$\ce{Ca(s) + C(s) + O3(g) -> CaCO3}$ ?

For example in another similar question:

> Choose the reaction that illustrates $\Delta H^\circ_\mathrm f$ for $\ce{Ca(NO3)2}$.

**Answer:** $\ce{Ca(s) + N2(g) + 3 O2(g) -> Ca(NO3)2(s)}$

**Can someone confirm this assumption of mine:**  it's ok to use fractions in these types of equations to blance it out as long as it's in oxygen's coefficient.

As that assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heat of formation refers to the formation of **one** mole of the compound from its elements in their **natural** states at $1\mathrm{~atm}$ and $298\mathrm{~K}$.  Your first example forms 2 moles and your second example uses ozone, which is not the "natural state" of oxygen at $298\mathrm{~K}$ and $1\mathrm{~atm}$.

Regarding your question about oxygen, it has nothing to do specifically with oxygen. The important thing is to have 1 mole of the compound on the right hand side of the equation.

Comment: Since 1982, $p=1\ \mathrm{bar}=100\,000\ \mathrm{Pa}$ (not $1\ \mathrm{atm}$) is used as the standard pressure for tabulating thermodynamic data. Furthermore, the definition of standard states make no reference to fixed temperature. It is possible to have a standard state at various temperatures. Hence, the assumed temperature should be indicated, e.g. $\Delta_\mathrm fH^\circ(298.15\ \mathrm K)$. It is true though that $T=298.15\ \mathrm K$ is the most favoured and the one recommended for use.

Comment: 298.15 is typically the temperature that applies to the heats of formation you find tabulated  in books.  According to Smith and Van Ness, Introduction to Chemical Engineering Thermodynamics, "The usual choice for this temperature is 298.15  K, or 25 C."